# Docker Port Not Exposing Golang

Tags: docker, networking

I am building a golang WebService in docker.  The build seems fine but I am unable to expose the port for external (outside of container) access.  When I curl from the command line (inside the container) the app appears to work fine.

I saw quite a few posts of similar problems but unfortunately many were not resolved or didn't seem applicable.

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN mkdir /go/src/webservice_refArch
ADD . /go/src/webservice_refArch
WORKDIR /go/src/webservice_refArch
RUN apk add curl
RUN cd /go/src/webservice_refArch/ && go get ./...
RUN cd /go/src/webservice_refArch/cmd/reference-w-s-server && go build -o ../../server
EXPOSE 7878
ENTRYPOINT ["./server", "--port=7878"]
```

I have tried both:

- :7878
- localhost:7878

Comment: Are you publishing the port when running the container with the `-p 7878:7878` parameter?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. Then what I did is change the ListernHost from localhost to 0.0.0.0 and it worked.

To debug this tried curl inside the container it was working fine but outside the container the response of the curl was blank. The port mapped but the content was not served outside the container. Once you change the "localhost" to 0.0.0.0 it will work.

Comment: This actually worked. Save me a day of debugging

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports, just expose port in dockerfile is not enough.

You can add `-p 7878:7878` when start container, or use `-P` to let docker set a automatical host port mapping for you.

If you do not want to do above, you can also add `--net=host` when start the container, then container will use host's network, if also works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Interestingly, the "--net=host" worked but both "-P" or "-p 7878:7878" didn't work.  When I do "--net=host" I can hit "localhost:7878/users/123" and it works.  When I do "-p 7878:7878" then it doesn't work.   I tried <dockerIP>:7878/users/123" and got a Connection Refused Error.  Something is clearly fubar with my network.

Comment: What's your docker version? Docker on windows or docker on linux? Could it work if restart docker daemon? Or could you try to use `http://real_host_ip:7878/users/123` to access not `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access the port inside your docker container from your local machine, you need map it to the desired port on your local machine

`docker run -p 7878:7878 IMAGE`

Then you should be able to access it on your host